# Let A a Invertible n.n matrix and Let X and Y be vectors In C^n

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A a Invertible n.n matrix and Let X and Y be vectors In C^n Why A^-1.X.Y^* is a matrix of rank 1 and why the eigen values of this matrix different from 0 is Y^*.A^-1^.X

Comment: You need to assume that $x$ and $y$ are non-zero

Comment: See [this brief introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to posting mathematical notation.  It will help to better organize and illustrate your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is of rank one because it sends everything orthogonal to $Y$ to $0,$ and it sends $Y$ to $A^{-1} X \|Y\|^2.$

For eigenvalues, see above.